# How do I properly setup AlloSystem and all of its dependencies?

Tags: cmake

I'm having difficulty running even the simplest AlloSystem tutorial. I'm trying to get up and running using AlloSystem, and I've followed the instructions as well as I can on their github here 
https://github.com/AlloSphere-Research-Group/AlloSystem

and their guide here 
https://github.com/AlloSphere-Research-Group/Allosystem-Guide

My issue is when I try running the tutorials even after using their ./install_add_dependencies script on all of the submodules, I get issues when I try to run ./run.sh allotutorial.cpp. This is the console output:

```
RUN SCRIPT: Building file projects/allotutorial.cpp.
CMake Warning at cmake_modules/make_dep.cmake:31 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcuttlebone.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "cuttlebone", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cuttlebone" with
  any of the following names:

    cuttleboneConfig.cmake
    cuttlebone-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "cuttlebone" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "cuttlebone_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "cuttlebone" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:108 (make_dep)


Cuttlebone required to build AlloSphere. Not found!
Using AlloSystem Run facilties.
----Building /home/sam/Documents/Sound/Library/AlloSystem/projects/allotutorial.cpp
Not building GAMMA and no usable GAMMA binary found. Not linking application to GAMMA
Not building GLV and no usable GLV binary found. Not linking application to GLV
Not building Cuttlebone and no usable Cuttlebone binary found. Not linking application to Cuttlebone
Not building allocv and no usable allocv binary found. Not linking application to allocv
Not building allosphere and no usable allosphere binary found. Not linking application to allosphere
make: *** No rule to make target 'projects_allotutorial_run'.  Stop.
```

How do I properly get all of my dependencies so that CMake can find them and ./run.sh can succeed?

Comment: Can you provide details how you built the Allo libraries that the examples use? What compiler and cmake are you using?  Also what directory are you in when running the `run.sh` file?

Comment: At [CMakeLists.txt:108](https://github.com/AlloSphere-Research-Group/AlloSystem/blob/devel/CMakeLists.txt#L108) they have `make_dep(cuttlebone)`, which eventually calls `find_package` with the same name, and it needs `Findcuttlebone.cmake` script to proceed. But they have only `FindCuttlebone.cmake` one (note: `C` is in **upper case**). Report the problem to developers. (In your installation you may replace `make_dep(cuttlebone)` with `make_dep(Cuttlebone)`.